# Do I need to use AWS S3 or EC2 for backend of my iOS app?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm new to AWS and not sure which product to use for my iOS app. I will brief the requirement of my sample app:

1. I need to create a table named "Recipes" with columns Name,Type,Image,Ingredients.

2.My app will load all data from table "Recipes" into tableviewController which includes images and string type of data.

Based on above need what should I use S3 or EC2 ?

Thanks

Comment: In which purpose you want to use AWS can you explain more

Comment: @BhupatBheda Bheda - my purpose is to store recipe information on server so that my ios app can access it.

Comment: Ok@Manish then you can you awsdynamo db for store recipe information in S3 you can only store image here

Comment: @Macabeus - i will try

Answer (score 4):

AWS EC2 and S3 are two different component and are for different purpose all together -

- AWS EC2 - Think it as a virtual machine where you can host the db and
  server or any one of it. Which means its not the Database. It is an
  OS where you will install the database.

  AWS S3 - S3 is a static storage which means you don't use it to store
  tabular data or data related to application, what you can store here
  is static files which you can download using

APIs consumed in your application.

Based on above two facts you should use either dynamodb for NoSql db and data, or any of relational databse available as service from AWS. Or you can install any of database of your choice in EC2 instance and use it for data persistence.